# How to create custom autocomplete list for QT Creator for custom language?

Tags: qt, autocomplete

Hy. I would like to use custom programming language (so not C++ etc.., it is my company own language) with QT creator, the sintax highlight is working, but where to insert the keyword of this language to use QT the autocomplete for this language? For example there is Put, Modify etc.. commands and if programmer start type: mod then this complete to Modify after ctrl + space.

Comment: You can create plugin with custom autocompletion for your language.